# Enable resizable & moveable modal dialogs in GNOME 3 on a per-application bases

Tags: gtk, gnome

GNOME in their infinite wisdom have decided that modal dialogs should not be moveable or resizable.

This can be disabled globally by changing a GConf setting:

https://superuser.com/questions/925115/gnome3-annoyances-how-to-fix-un-resizeable-windows

Is it possible for an application to request disabling this behaviour just for itself?